# NiFi's ExcecuteScript works fine with 1 task but fails with concurrent tasks

Tags: java, python, apache-nifi

I am using Python in ExecuteScript which works perfectly fine when run with 1 task, but fails when I set the concurrent task property to more than 1. My script looks like this.

```
class ModJSON(StreamCallback):
  #implementation goes here
  ...
 
flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:
  try:
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", flowFile.getAttribute('filename').split('.')[0] + '_translated.json')
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
  except Exception as e:
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
  finally:
    session.commit()
```

And the error I get is this. Any idea what is wrong in my code?

[image]

Comment: You don't have to commit() the session, ExecuteScript does that for you

Comment: Thanks @mattyb. I had already shifted to groovy and that worked fine.